# Geometry size assistant in QGIS ignores one of my data columns

Tags: qgis, geojson

I am trying to display geometry sizes by numerical weight with the geometry size assistant in QGIS and am using this GeoJSON layer:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ieg-dhr/DigiKAR_Projektseminar/main/GeoJSON%20layers/Domherren_v6.geojson

The size assistant permits me to select the `place_count` as well as the `e_count` columns but ignores the `s_count` column. Why is that? I could not find an error in the GeoJSON file that would prevent the data from loading.

**EDIT:**

I have now figured out that QGIS sees that data column as an "ABC" (text) column although all values are numerical and not strings. I could not identify any strings in the column and would like to know how I can change its "type" in QGIS without downloading the data from QGIS and importing from my local drive.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like some bad version of GDAL or QGIS might be involved there, it works fine for me on QGIS 3.26.3 with GDAL 3.5.1. All three columns are detected as numeric values.

As a workaround you can use an expression instead of the vanilla column. Click the Epsilon (like an mirrored "3") next to the dropdown where you can select the column and enter the expression `to_int("s_count")`.

Comment: Thanks! At the end of the day, I just downloaded the file and it worked, but pulling it in directly from Github as a raw file is much handier. I will definitely update to the latest version of QGIS. I have had quite some glitches for the past few weeks.

Comment: Oh I missed that in your question. It works when opened locally but not when opened as remote file? It seems to work for me if I copy and paste the URL into the Data Source Manager's Vector dialog as well.

Comment: Yes, for me it only worked locally but not remotely.